# Need to find the number of strings starting with each character of the alphabet. Using SQL Developer from Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got large a database with single words (no spaces) and I need to find how many times does a string start with every character in the alphabet. So, the output would be, let's say :

```
a    {}    10
b    {}    63
```

And so on. I have no clue where to even start.

Comment: Which database engine are you on? MySql?

Comment: `select substring(col from 1 for 1), count(*) from tab group by substring(col from 1 for 1)`

Comment: I'm using SQL Developer from Oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT    SUBSTR(LOWER(col), 1, 1) AS letter,
          COUNT(*)
FROM      mytable
GROUP BY  SUBSTR(LOWER(col), 1, 1);
```

Where *col* is the name of the column you want to get the first letter from.

Comment: I'll try that just now.

Comment: Syntax depends on your database engine.

Comment: I'm using SQL Developer from Oracle and it doesn't recognise LEFT as an identifier.

Comment: Updated answer. Use substr with extra parameter.

Comment: You're welcome. I tagged your question with "Oracle".

Comment: Was waiting for stackoverflow to let me accept your answer. Did it now. Thanks for all your help.